# Mathematica Code to create geometries

Tags: graphics, geometry

I want to create geometries. How to create shapes like this in Mathematica?
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally, graphics primitives like `Polygon`, `Triangle`, `Disk` and `MeshRegion`-related functions such as `RegionDifference` and `RegionUnion` may help you.

As a starting point for you, here is example D:

```
R = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[
 RegionDifference[
  Rectangle[{0, 0}, {10, 2}],
  BoundaryDiscretizeRegion@RegionUnion[
    Triangle[{{2, 1}, {4, 1}, {3, 0}}],
    Disk[{7.5, 0.5}, 1/Sqrt[2]]
    ]
  ]
 ]
```

I suggest to look up the used symbols in the documentation. Moreover, each documentation page has links to further related symbols. See also `Graphics` for setting up scenes (including axes, coloring, filling style etc.)

Answer (score 7):

Like Henrik says, it is possible to use the region functionality in Mathematica to define those regions using unions and complements. Another way to define regions is by specifying their boundaries. To this end, Mathematica has a function called `FilledCurve`:

```
Graphics[{
  FaceForm[LightBlue],
  EdgeForm[{Thick, Red}],
  FilledCurve@Line[{
     {0, 0},
     {2, 0},
     {3, 1},
     {4, 0},
     {7, 0},
     {7.5, 1},
     {8, 0},
     {10, 0},
     {10, 2},
     {0, 2}
     }]
  },
 Axes -> True,
 Ticks -> {Range[10], Range[2]},
 PlotRangePadding -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To get the curved shapes, you may use graphics primitives such as `BezierCurve` and `BSplineCurve`.

Even if you choose to work with unions and complements you may want to use `FilledCurve` to create regions that you can work with. For example, there is no primitive that will allow you create those curved regions directly, but you can easily create them by combining e.g. `BezierCurve` and `FilledCurve`.

(Being able to use segments like `BezierCurve` is also one of the reasons why `FilledCurve` is preferred over `Polygon`; the simple example in this post could also be created using `Polygon` but it only works so long as the boundary consists of straight lines.)

This approach also handles geometries with holes in them, but I refer to the documentation for the details on that.